# Directing pointer to struct causes expression syntax error

Tags: c, syntax-error, expression, turbo-c

This maybe a completely obvious error but I can't figure out why my code below won't work. I'm rather unfamiliar with C, though I have made some programs using it.

I'm using Turbo C (v.3.2), so that might also be the issue; however, I'm not sure.

```
static struct sector
{
    float floor, ceil;
    vec2 *verts;
    signed char *neighbors;
    unsigned npoints;
}*sectors = NULL;
static unsigned NumSectors = 0;

static struct player
{
    vec3 position, velocity;
    float anlge, anglesin, anglecos, yaw;
    unsigned sector;
}player;

void DrawScreen()
{
    enum{ MaxQueue = 32 };
    unsigned s = 0;
    struct item { int sectorno,sx1, sx2; } queue[MaxQueue], *head=queue, *tail=queue;
    int ytop[W]={0}, ybottom[W], *renderedsectors = (int*)malloc(NumSectors*sizeof(int));
    for(s = 0; s < W; ++s) ybottom[s] = H-1;
    for(s = 0; s < NumSectors; ++s) renderedsectors[s] = 0;

    //This line causes an Expression syntax error.
    //From my understanding the pointer is moved to this structure inside the array.
    //Corrections welcome as I want to learn c more in order to
    //use it in more projects of mine.
    *head = (struct item) { player.sector, 0, W-1 };
    if(++head == queue+MaxQueue) head = queue;

    do{

        const struct item now = *tail;
        const struct sector* const sect = &sectors[now.sectorno];
        if(++tail == queue+MaxQueue) tail = queue;

        if(renderedsectors[now.sectorno] & 0x21) continue;
        ++renderedsectors[now.sectorno];
        for(s = 0; s < sect->npoints; ++s)
        {

        }
    }while(head != tail);
}
```

I'm aware of the age of Turbo C but I have to use it due to it running in DOSBox, where my final executable has to work.

I'm copying the code from [this](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/jutut/kuvat/programming_examples/portalrendering/prender.c) website and I'm pretty sure he used another compiler, which probably was also newer.

I didn't work a lot with C and I mostly either used C++ in my free time or C# on the job, but I need to use it now due to the restrictions I'm facing.

Comment: sooo which line causes the error?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KamilCuk I have written comments that show where the error occurs and what I understand the code is supposed to do( I haven't written it myself)

Comment: @picchiolu It's a compiler error, if you use the same compiler(either exactly or just for the c version) as me you will recieve it

Comment: We can’t compile an incomplete program. Please, read what a minimal reproducible example is by following the link I provided and try to showcase the problem in the shortest possible program that still produces the error/issue you’d like us to help you with.

Comment: @picchiolu litteraly all you have to do is add a main() function and you are ready to go. It's a compiler error

Comment: @KaySteinhoff well, vec2 and vec3 don’t seem to be standard C types, so I guess my compiler will complain about those first. Instead of asking us to work around the shortcomings of your code sample, please try to provide a program that can be compiled without non-standard includes. That’s what a minimal reproducible sample is about.

Comment: "All you have to do is add a main() function". This is putting the burden on the wrong person.  The reader shouldn't have to do anything.  If you expect people to help you, you should be willing to provide a complete example that does not require them to do anything, even if you think the amount of work is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code that is causing your error message (shown below) is using what is known as a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). This allows an anonyomus object of the type specified in the parentheses to be constructed from the data provided in the initializer list (inside the braces).

```c
*head = (struct item) { player.sector, 0, W-1 };
```

The problem you're facing is that this construct was only incorporated into the C language in the "C99" (formally, ISO/IEC 9899:1999) [version of the Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) – which, as it's name implies, was published in 1999.

However, the compiler you are using (Turbo C, v3.2) was released [in or around 1993](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B), so it almost certainly does not support this feature. (Some pre-1999 compilers may have supported compound literals as extensions but I doubt that Turbo C was one of them.)

There are two things you can do to circumvent the error:

1. Use a more modern (i.e. less than 20 years old) compiler.
2. Create an explicit temporary structure and assign that to the `*head` target:

```c
    struct item temp = { player.sector, 0, W - 1 };
    *head = temp;
```

Note that, in the second case, your `temp` variable will have the same scope (and lifetime) as the anonymous object created by the compound literal.